# dudas de cardinalidad en base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos

Cuando relaciono tablas en una base de datos pueden existir relaciones uno es a uno, uno es a muchos o muchos a muchos, pero tengo la duda de ciertas plataformas que ponen un valor zero también. A que se refiere este valor?

Comment: cero o uno son valores validos para las relaciones.. imagina la relacion persona - hijos.. puede tener de 0 a muchos...

Comment: ¿Que ponen el valor `cero` dónde específicamente? Supongamos que tienes un `id` que es igual a cero, ese id puede servir como cualquier otro valor para las relaciones... para cualquier tipo de relación de las mencionadas en tu pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano se refiere a relaciones 0...n.. mira mi comentario... es sobre cardinalidad...

Comment: Así es, me refería a cardinalidad, más que nada por el software SQL Power Architect que agrega todas estas relaciones con zero. En todo caso ahora me queda más claro.